# Determining whitespace in Go

Tags: unicode, go, whitespace

From the [documentation of Go's `unicode` package](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsSpace):

> **func IsSpace**
>
> `func IsSpace(r rune) bool`
>
> IsSpace reports whether the rune is a space character as defined by Unicode's White Space property; in the Latin-1 space this is
>
> `'\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', ' ', U+0085 (NEL), U+00A0 (NBSP).`
>
> Other definitions of spacing characters are set by category Z and property Pattern_White_Space.

My question is: What does it mean that "other definitions" are set by the Z category and `Pattern_White_Space`? Does this mean that calling `unicode.IsSpace()`, checking whether a character is in the Z category, and checking whether a character is in `Pattern_White_Space` **will all yield different results?** If so, what are the differences? And why are there differences?

Answer (score 5):

The IsSpace function will first check if your `rune` is in the Latin1 char space.  If it is, it will use the space characters you listed to determine white-spacing.

If not, `isExcludingLatin` (http://golang.org/src/unicode/letter.go?h=isExcludingLatin#L170) is called which looks like:

```
   170  func isExcludingLatin(rangeTab *RangeTable, r rune) bool {
   171      r16 := rangeTab.R16
   172      if off := rangeTab.LatinOffset; len(r16) > off && r <= rune(r16[len(r16)-1].Hi) {
   173          return is16(r16[off:], uint16(r))
   174      }
   175      r32 := rangeTab.R32
   176      if len(r32) > 0 && r >= rune(r32[0].Lo) {
   177          return is32(r32, uint32(r))
   178      }
   179      return false
   180  }
```

The `*RangeTable` being passed in is `White_Space` which looks is defined here:

http://golang.org/src/unicode/tables.go?h=White_Space#L6069

```
  6069  var _White_Space = &RangeTable{
  6070      R16: []Range16{
  6071          {0x0009, 0x000d, 1},
  6072          {0x0020, 0x0020, 1},
  6073          {0x0085, 0x0085, 1},
  6074          {0x00a0, 0x00a0, 1},
  6075          {0x1680, 0x1680, 1},
  6076          {0x2000, 0x200a, 1},
  6077          {0x2028, 0x2029, 1},
  6078          {0x202f, 0x202f, 1},
  6079          {0x205f, 0x205f, 1},
  6080          {0x3000, 0x3000, 1},
  6081      },
  6082      LatinOffset: 4,
  6083  }
```

To answer your main question, the `IsSpace` check is not limited to Latin-1.

**EDIT**
For clarification, if the character you are testing is not in the Latin-1 charset, then the range table lookup is used.  The `Range16` values in the table represent ranges of 16bit numbers {Low, Hi, Stride}.  The `isExcludingLatin` will call `is16` with that range table sub-section (`R16`) and determine if the `rune` provided falls in any of the ranges after the index of `LatinOffset` (which is 4 in this case).

So, that is checking these ranges:

```
 {0x1680, 0x1680, 1},
 {0x2000, 0x200a, 1},
 {0x2028, 0x2029, 1},
 {0x202f, 0x202f, 1},
 {0x205f, 0x205f, 1},
 {0x3000, 0x3000, 1},
```

There are unicode code points for:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1680/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2000/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2001/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2004/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2005/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2006/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2008/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200a/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205f/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm

All of the above are considers "white space"

Comment: So what is the white-box difference between calling `unicode.IsSpace()`, checking whether a character is in the Z category, and checking whether a character is in `Pattern_White_Space`? In other words, which characters are considered whitespace by one of these methods but not by another?

Comment: But the question is how is that different from checking whether a character is in the Z category or in `Pattern_White_Space`?